# Можно ли улучшить работу GPS программно?

Tags: android, gps

У меня сотовый телефон на базе Android. Тестирую на нём свою программу определения местоположения по GPS. Иногда работает, мягко говоря, странновато.

Например, я выключил телефон или отключил GPS в настройках телефона. Через какое-то время включаю телефон и/или GPS. Однако, телефон показывает старое местоположение. Причем, это не только в моей программе, но на Гугл-картах или 2ГИС.

GPS начинает сам работает, только если походить с включенным телефоном)), иначе показывает старое местоположение.

Возможно ли в моей программе задать какое-нибудь обнуление GPS, чтобы телефон переинициализировался и выдал истинное местоположение?

Comment: Какого провайдера вы используете в LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()? GPS_PROVIDER? Указываете его вообще? Ориентируйтесь на то, что GPS - штука не быстрая, работает не везде и с большим кол-вом ограничений. A-GPS есть сейчас практически во всех телефонах, но API к нему в андроиде нет и в любом случае для его работы у телефона должен быть доступ к интернету.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется "холодный старт" самого GPS чипа в телефоне. Т.е оно при первом включении на холодную еще не поймало все спутники и фактически не отдает никаких данных программам. Теже гуглкарты и 2гис показывают ваши координаты из кэша.

Вы конечно можете програмно обнулить кэш, но это не значит что он сразу же найдет ваше местоположение, т.к. еще не получает данные со спутника. По этому и надо "походить с включенным телефоном" пока сам GPS чип не начнет полностью функционировать и отдавать координаты.

Comment: Я нашёл как ускорить работу на своём телефоне: http://4pda.ru/2014/09/25/177874/ . Не знаю как работает, не проверял, но это не подходит - программа должна быть установлена не только на моём телефоне. Возможно, своей программой так ускорить?

Comment: Я у себя использую программу под названием [Статус GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=ru) - она использует так называемую технологию A-GPS и позволяет улучшить точность и скорость запуска программ использующих GPS чип

Comment: @sitev_ru все эти "ускорители GPS" - это обычно пляски с бубном вокруг кривых настроек на дешевых китайских телефонах на чипе MTK. На нормальных телефонах это всё все работает из коробки. Разработчику приложений об этом знать, а тем более использовать, не нужно, потому что вмешиваться в работу системных сервисов обычное приложение не должно.